# Int List To Integer List

Tags: list, haskell

How do I convert an `Int` list to an `Integer` list?

I've only found solutions that work for one `Int`.

I'm getting this error

```
Couldn't match type `Int' with `Integer'
Expected type: [Integer]
  Actual type: [Int]
```

when forcing

```
:: [Integer] -> Integer
```

and

```
Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Int'
```

when forcing

```
:: [Int] -> Int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map `toInteger` over the list.

```
Prelude> let l = [1,2,3] :: [Int]
Prelude> :t l
l :: [Int]
Prelude> map toInteger l
[1,2,3]
Prelude> :t map toInteger l
map toInteger l :: [Integer]
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it work to map your found solution to the entire list using

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromIntegral` to convert from any integral type (`Int`, `Integer`, `Char`, `Word8`, etc.) to any `Num` type which, of course, includes the integral types.

So one way of converting `[Int]` to `[Integer]` is:

```
map fromIntegral
```